# Light Novel where a hero is summoned and mistakenly killed multiple times

Tags: story-identification, novel

I'm looking for the title of a light novel that I can't find any more. It was the story of a character who is summoned to different worlds because he is killed each time.

He is summoned as a hero but he is killed because his aura is terrifying for the people who summon him. He is invoked successively in 100 different worlds (in my memories) and finally the gods of these worlds invoke him and meet him, apologizing for the error of their respective peoples and leaving him the choice of the world in which he wants to be reincarnated.

They ask to be reincarnated in a world where there are humans, etc. and I remember that the world goddess he had chosen had a very long name which formed a ridiculous acronym (f.a.r.g.e or w.o.r.m).

Comment: oh from title I thought it was re:zero

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is *[The Unwanted Hero](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/52098084-the-unwanted-hero)* by Cristian Madalin Dragomir.

> Chosen by a force far beyond his imagination, a man from modern day Earth finds himself sent to a world of myth and legend, of magic and fantasy, yet… just as quickly as he was summoned, he was rejected by the people there and sent back in a violent way. **Then he was summoned again and again and again… a whole 118 times,** until the very Gods who governed those 118 different worlds had enough and unanimously decided to cut the man from a life of heroism and instead grant him a peaceful and stress-free reincarnated life!
> Or, at the very least… that was supposed to be the plan.